# Change the Text in HTML with span class using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use a JavaScript function to change the text in an html span using the class name, but is not working. There is an element with the text "My Tasks", and I am trying to write what I thought was going to be an easy JS function to change the text, but cannot figure it out.

```js
console.log('forgot my JavaScript here');
```

```css
.helpme {
  color: red;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="helpme">I need html here please</div>
```

[image: Screenshot of part of HTML body]

Comment: Please do not provide HTML as an image. Type (copy) the text and format it (using toolbar or single lines of three backticks). Secondly, as you are trying with JavaScript, please add your current code, and explain what exactly is not working and what you have found while debugging it.

Comment: I made a snippet where you can place your great HTML and JavaScipt so we can best assist you here.

Comment: Asking about how we can help fix your JavaScript and then not including any in your question is not going to get you your best answers here.

Answer (score 1):

to help javascript find the element give it an id:

```
<span id="foobar" class="toolbartitle">My Tasks</span>
```

then do

```
document.getElementById("foobar").innerHTML = "New Text!";
```

Note that using a class to find an element is dangerous because generally classes are not unique whereas ids exist to be unique, though HTML will not stop you from duplicating them.

Comment: OP specifically says "using the class name"

Comment: Fair enough, though what someone wants to do isn't always what they should do

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind that using the class you could customize more than one element

**Example:**

```js
document.querySelector('.your-class').textContent = "Test 2";
```

```html
<span class="your-class">Test 1</span>
```

You can find more information about the **querySelector** *attribute* here: [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)